# Errors while compiling on macOS for the CryptoNote Starter

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a cryptocurrency with the CryptoNote Starter (cryptonotestarter.org), but get some errors when I try compiling (I think it uses cmake, make, and boost). Here are the errors:

```
mkdir -p build/debug
cd build/debug && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The ASM compiler identification is AppleClang
-- Found assembler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Boost version: 1.68.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   chrono
--   regex
--   serialization
--   program_options
--   atomic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.10") 
CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
  CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES was enabled even though installation rules have
  been specified


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/crypthusiast0/downloads/hydro-master/build/debug
cd build/debug && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
Scanning dependencies of target version
[  0%] Built target version
Scanning dependencies of target upnpc-static
[  1%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/igd_desc_parse.c.o
[  1%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/miniupnpc.c.o
[  1%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/minixml.c.o
[  1%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/minisoap.c.o
[  2%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/miniwget.c.o
[  2%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/upnpc.c.o
[  2%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/upnpcommands.c.o
[  3%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/upnpreplyparse.c.o
[  3%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/upnperrors.c.o
[  3%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/connecthostport.c.o
[  4%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/portlistingparse.c.o
[  4%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/receivedata.c.o
[  4%] Building C object external/miniupnpc/CMakeFiles/upnpc-static.dir/minissdpc.c.o
[  5%] Linking C static library libminiupnpc.a
[  5%] Built target upnpc-static
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[  5%] Building CXX object external/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[  6%] Linking CXX static library libgtest.a
[  6%] Built target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target gtest_main
[  6%] Building CXX object external/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
[  6%] Linking CXX static library libgtest_main.a
[  6%] Built target gtest_main
Scanning dependencies of target Common
[  6%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/Base58.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/BlockingQueue.cpp.o
/Users/crypthusiast0/downloads/hydro-master/src/Common/BlockingQueue.cpp:8:6: warning: unused variable 'suppressMSVCWarningLNK4221' [-Wunused-variable]
char suppressMSVCWarningLNK4221;
     ^
1 warning generated.
[  7%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/CommandLine.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/ConsoleHandler.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/ConsoleTools.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/IInputStream.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/IOutputStream.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/JsonValue.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/Math.cpp.o
/Users/crypthusiast0/downloads/hydro-master/src/Common/Math.cpp:8:6: warning: unused variable 'suppressMSVCWarningLNK4221' [-Wunused-variable]
char suppressMSVCWarningLNK4221;
     ^
1 warning generated.
[  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/MemoryInputStream.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/PathTools.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/ScopeExit.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/SignalHandler.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/StdInputStream.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/StdOutputStream.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/StreamTools.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/StringInputStream.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/StringOutputStream.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/StringTools.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/StringView.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/Util.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Common/VectorOutputStream.cpp.o
[ 13%] Linking CXX static library libCommon.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(BlockingQueue.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(IInputStream.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(IOutputStream.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(Math.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(BlockingQueue.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(IInputStream.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(IOutputStream.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libCommon.a(Math.cpp.o) has no symbols
[ 13%] Built target Common
Scanning dependencies of target BlockchainExplorer
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/BlockchainExplorer.dir/BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorer.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/BlockchainExplorer.dir/BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorerDataBuilder.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/crypthusiast0/downloads/hydro-master/src/BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorerDataBuilder.cpp:5:
/Users/crypthusiast0/downloads/hydro-master/src/BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorerDataBuilder.h:38:41: warning: private field 'protocol' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
  CryptoNote::ICryptoNoteProtocolQuery& protocol;
                                        ^
1 warning generated.
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/BlockchainExplorer.dir/BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorerErrors.cpp.o
[ 14%] Linking CXX static library libBlockchainExplorer.a
[ 14%] Built target BlockchainExplorer
Scanning dependencies of target Serialization
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/BinaryInputStreamSerializer.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/BinaryOutputStreamSerializer.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/JsonInputStreamSerializer.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/JsonInputValueSerializer.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/JsonOutputStreamSerializer.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/KVBinaryInputStreamSerializer.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/KVBinaryOutputStreamSerializer.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/MemoryStream.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Serialization.dir/Serialization/SerializationOverloads.cpp.o
[ 17%] Linking CXX static library libSerialization.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libSerialization.a(MemoryStream.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libSerialization.a(MemoryStream.cpp.o) has no symbols
[ 17%] Built target Serialization
Scanning dependencies of target System
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/System.dir/Platform/OSX/System/Context.c.o
In file included from /Users/crypthusiast0/downloads/hydro-master/src/Platform/OSX/System/Context.c:6:
/Users/crypthusiast0/downloads/hydro-master/src/Platform/OSX/System/Context.h:19:40: error: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Werror,-Wstrict-prototypes]
extern  void            makecontext(uctx*, void(*)(), intptr_t);
                                                  ^
                                                   void
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/System.dir/Platform/OSX/System/Context.c.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/System.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [build-debug] Error 2
```

This is from the cryptonotestarter, forked right from the Github page. You can find the forked version here-> https://github.com/crypthusiast/hydro. I don't know any cpp.

Comment: I am not familiar with that error message but it looks like a bug in their source. Did you pull the source from a master branch? Try downloading a specific version

Comment: Hmmm. As the error log says, there is an error in the code, I think. Here is the code you might want to look through: https://pastebin.com/fmXhUtTq

Comment: If you look closely as the CMake output, that file is being compiled as C code. You probably want to change the C++ tag to C because there are differences between the languages.

Comment: Can you show the output of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1`, specifically the call to clang that fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found a simple work-around, however I do not have a OSX machine to test it on.

1. Open `hydro/CMakeLists.txt`
2. Change `set(C_WARNINGS "-Waggregate-return -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes")` to `set(C_WARNINGS "-Waggregate-return -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wno-strict-prototypes")`
3. Run `cmake . && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make` in the `build/debug` directory

Or to disable `-Werror` for everything

1. Add `-Wno-error` to the **END** of the relevant (clang/c/c++) `WARNINGS` variables in `hydro/CMakeLists.txt`
2. Run `cmake .` in `build/debug`
3. Run `make` as usual

Comment: It sorta works. I get a new error you can find here: https://pastebin.com/wKVWPTmn

Comment: Try compiling a release build. They have Werror on so any warnings turn into compile errors. If that doesn’t work I’ll try to find another workaround

Comment: Ok, thanks! What ever flags I try with make, it only goes about until 30% then terminates, coming out with error 2.

Comment: With Werror on, it turns gcc warning into compile errors. It’s meant to find potential bugs while developing. It doesn’t change the behavior of the code so turning it off will allow the code to compile as-is

Comment: okay. I tried turning off all the warning settings and got to 67%. I will try to play around with it.

Comment: My theory is that a Release build will disable all the warnings for you, but I'm not sure